# Парсинг страниц одинаковой верстки, но с изменением данных

Tags: php, html, github, github-pages

Есть небольшой сайтик на HTML, CSS и JS. Мне приходится создавать несколько страниц с одинаковой версткой, но с изменением нескольких данных. Я хотел сделать весь сайт через PHP-файлы, что-то наподобии `expert.php?id=1`, но вспомнил что **GitHub Pages** не поддерживает PHP. Так вот, мне нужна **система сборки** для сайта, чтобы мне было удобно в одном файле хранить верстку, а в остальных данные, которые нужно будет вставлять в эту верстку.

Comment: Я бы еще посмотрел в сторону [Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser/). Но с ним не работал, так что не могу ничего конкретного утверждать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> С помощью Handlebars вы сможете построить эффективные семантические
>   шаблоны. Шаблоны Handlebars во многом совместимы с шаблонами Mustache
>   — в большинстве случаев они взаимозаменяемы. Полные сведения можно
>   найти по этой ссылке.

https://habr.com/post/273581/
https://handlebarsjs.com